# Need syntax to call powermock whitebox()

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

In my unit tests I'm trying to execute a private method using Whitebox.invokeMethod, but I don't know the syntax that works.  I want to invoke this (getExcelMappingJsoDto() is the private method) but not sure how to pass arguments

```
Map<Integer,String> columnMapping = genericExcelCreator.getExcelMappingJsoDto().getSheets().get(0).getColumnMapping();
```

Trying something like this, to no avail:

```
Map<Integer,String> columnMapping  = Whitebox.invokeMethod(genericExcelCreator, "getExcelMappingJsoDto().getSheets().get(0).getColumnMapping", null);
```

Comment: genericExcelCreator should be mocked, if I'm not mistaken. And then I would pass "getExcelMappingJsoDto" as the method to be invoked. Whatever that method returns could be then called upon with .getSheets().get(0).getColumnMapping().

Comment: @Paul Right, I did what you suggested and got it working. If you can respond in an answer then I can accept it. Thanks1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get Whitebox to work, you'll need to mock your `GenericExcelCreator` class.
For example, using Mockito's annotations:

```
@Mock
private GenericExcelCreator genericExcelCreator;
```

Usually, I'd assign the return value of the method to a new variable before I start working with it. Since I don't know your return type, but keeping in mind that Java allows method-chaining, you could do it like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> columnMapping = Whitebox.invokeMethod(genericExcelCreator, "getExcelMappingJsoDto").getSheets().get(0).getColumnMapping();
```

Keep in mind that Whitebox only needs the (method)name, so you shouldn't add the brackets () when passing it along to `.invokeMethod`

Additionally, another common use of Whitebox is changing the value of a private variable in a mocked class. This you can achieve by:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(yourMockedService, "nameOfYourVariable", variableObjectTypeValue);
```

For example, I could have a class `CleanupService` with an interchangeable boolean called `allowCleanup` that I want to test when `false`.
This results in:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(cleanupService, "allowCleanup", false);
```